# Reading a file and storing them into a 2D Array of Objects in Java?

Tags: java, file, object, multidimensional-array

I have a project in Java I am trying to do (for fun) but I am struggling in this step. I have cities I am trying to read from two countries, the United States and China and I am having trouble reading the file in. I am trying to use a delimiter to separate the cities in China and The United States.

Here is my text file "Cities.txt"

> San Francisco 9874343 543443 193838
>
> Los Angeles 3900000 52000 22000
>
> Baltimore 622104 34423 1234
>
> Houston 2196000 45444 29393
>
> New York City 8500000 54000 27000
>
> Philadelphia 1510000 654334 21343
>
> Boston 6423344 345334 13443
>
> Chicago 2719000 39000 19282
>
> San Diego 1323343 432343 18374
>
> Dallas 1258000 423343 17363 |
>
> Beijing 21500000 32454 23454
>
> Hangzhouu 9018000 32343 192828
>
> Shanghia 24500000 432345 23444
>
> GuangZhou 20800654 323455 298383
>
> Wuhan 10670000 54344 302344
>
> Swatow 5391028 43345 23235
>
> Hong Kong 7234800 39039 278383
>
> Macau 650900 34543 17364
>
> Shenzhen 10630000 44343 19883
>
> Zibo 2980000 49383 20009

Here is my main Java class. I also have a Cities class with a constructor, getters/setters and a toString();

```
static Cities[][] multi = new Cities[2][10];



public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   System.out.println("The point of this program is to compare different cities in the two major superpower countries, \n The United States and China.");
System.out.println("The information in the cities in stored in a 2D array of Objects and is pre-created in a text files. \n Please pick an option to manipulate the information in the array.");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
String name = " "; 
int population = 0; 
double wage = 0.0;
int density = 0;
Cities cities = new Cities(name,population,wage,density); 

boolean exit = false; 
readcity(name);
String options = "1). Print all the cities. \n 2). Print just the united states cities. \n 3). Print just the China Cities \n 90). Exit program";
System.out.println(options);
int decide = in.nextInt();
while (!exit)
{
    switch (decide) {
        case 1:
        {
            printarray(name,population,wage,density);
        }
        case 2: {

        }
        case 3: {

        }

        case 90: {
            exit = true; 

        }
}

}
}


public static Cities readcity(String fline)
{
try {
  String name; int population; double wage; int density;        
    int countries = 2; int city = 10;   
     Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("/src/Cities.txt"));
   fileScan.useDelimiter("|"); 
    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
      name = fileScan.next();
      population = fileScan.nextInt();
      wage = fileScan.nextDouble(); 
      density = fileScan.nextInt();
     Cities City = new Cities(name, population, wage, density);
     return new Cities(name,population,wage,density);

    }




 fileScan.nextLine();   
Cities City = readcity(fline);
multi[countries][city] = City; 
return City;
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Looks like there was an error.");
  }
  Cities City = readcity(fline);
  return City;
  }
 public static void printarray(String name, int population, double wage, int density) throws FileNotFoundException{


 Cities cities = new Cities(name,population,wage,density); 

                   for (int row =0; row < multi.length; row++){
                       for (int column = 0; column < multi[row].length; column++){
                           System.out.println(multi[row][column]);
                       }
                       System.out.println();
                   }
                   cities.toString(); 
   }
   }
```

The method seems to be doing an infinite recursive call, but I am wondering how I would fix this. Would I do the same approach for two files and implement that way? Or would I take them out the method to read in the cities and implement them via a diffrent approach? I am weak with files handling and using a 2d array is even a heftier layer on top of that. Trying to fix my weaknesses so any help you can give me would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Well, where do I start...

1. Your readcity() method is calling itself recursively. I don't think this was the idea. Try removing these calls.
2. You initial call to readcity() is with the argument " ". Not sure what was the intention here.
3. Opening bracket "{" after "while (fileScan.hasNext())" is apparently lost in the code above.
4. In general, try naming your classes and variables according to their plurality. If an object is supposed to hold one city, its class should be called "City". If an object is supposed to hold a collection of cities, then you can call the class "Cities".

Answer (score 0):

No need for recursion to read from file in this situation. I definitely recommend writing comments so that an outside user knows what everything is doing basically. Um. I would also make getting the data from the file easier since you don't have much experience with file handling I'm assuming?.

I reformatted the file to make things easier in a sense. That way you can get each information between the ',' by using split.

```
US:
San Francisco, 9874343, 543443, 193838
Los Angeles, 3900000, 52000, 22000
Baltimore, 622104, 34423, 1234
Houston, 2196000, 45444, 29393
New York City, 8500000, 54000, 27000
Philadelphia, 1510000, 654334, 21343
Boston, 6423344, 345334, 13443
Chicago, 2719000, 39000, 19282
San Diego, 1323343, 432343, 18374
Dallas, 1258000, 423343, 17363
China:
Beijing, 21500000, 32454, 23454
Hangzhouu, 9018000, 32343, 192828
Shanghia, 24500000, 432345, 23444
GuangZhou, 20800654, 323455, 298383
Wuhan, 10670000, 54344, 302344
Swatow, 5391028, 43345, 23235
Hong Kong, 7234800, 39039, 278383
Macau, 650900, 34543, 17364
Shenzhen, 10630000, 44343, 19883
Zibo, 2980000, 49383, 20009
```

and this is the class I made to read the data and store in a 2d array of cities.

```
public class CityReader {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        City[][] cities = new City[2][10];
        readFileInto2D("src/Cities.txt",cities);
        //User prompt on what they want to here?    
        print2DArray(cities);
    }

    public static void readFileInto2D(String filename,City[][] cities)
    {
        City city;
        String name = "";
        int population = 0;
        int wage = 0;
        int density = 0;

        try {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            String line;
            String[] parsed;

            //Read US:
            if(scan.hasNext())
                line = scan.nextLine();

            //Keep track of rows
            int indexer = 0; 
            //Keep track of columns
            int indexer2 = 0;

            while(scan.hasNext())
            {
                line = scan.nextLine();

                if(line.contains("China"))
                {
                    indexer += 1;//Go to next row
                    indexer2 = 0;//Start index at beginning of column.
                    line = scan.nextLine();//Read next line, ignore line with China.
                }
                parsed = line.split(", "); //This splits each line 
                                           //into an array of name,pop,wage,and density
                name = parsed[0];
                population = Integer.parseInt(parsed[1]);
                wage = Integer.parseInt(parsed[2]);
                density = Integer.parseInt(parsed[3]);              
                city = new City(name,population,wage,density);              
                cities[indexer][indexer2] = city;//Add to 2D Array.             
                indexer2++;                             
            }


        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public static void print2DArray(City[][] cities)
    {
        //row
        for(int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
        {
            //column
            for(int j = 0; j < cities[i].length;j++)
            {
                City city = cities[i][j];
                //used getters to print information.
                System.out.printf("%s %d %d %d\n",city.getName(),
                        city.getPopulation(),city.getWage(),
                        city.getDensity());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this isn't perfect and a user can easily implement errors due to no error checking. This was more of showing one way to do it. The city class used is basic with just the constructor and getters and setters.

Comment: You are a life saver dude thank you! And yes you are correct I am not experienced with files and multi dimensional arrays for that matter and I'm trying get better at that.

Comment: Practice makers perfect! and You're welcome. Try to read more into recursion and what its used for and how to use it.